# NEW Relic. How can I get information about page visits for the last month for each day?

Tags: newrelic

I am trying to get the number of visits to the page for the last month (not calendar, but from the current date to the same date exactly one month ago, for example, if today is April 22, then I would like to get data from March 22). But I receive data simply for the full last month, not including the current one. Here is the script I use for this:

SELECT count(*) FROM PageView WHERE appName = 'appName' SINCE 1 month ago FACET dayOfMonthOf(timestamp)

Here is what I'm getting:

[image]

You can see that the dates are not tied to a specific month and it's impossible to understand whether 12 is March 12 or April 12.

In addition, I would like to understand if there is any way to measure the number of visits to a specific page of the project (a multi-page site), or will it be necessary to measure clicks on links to each specific page?